# netsuite case when formula

Tags: case, netsuite, rank, dense-rank

I am trying to make it so that when I have a case that either has Multiple Sales orders or multiple items on a sales order that it will tell me *Multiple SOs* on all of the lines..  So far the case formula code that I have will put it on some of the SOs but not all of them.  it always skips some.

The end result is so that we know that there is multiple sales orders associated with that case..  This will allow us to know to look for tracking for each sales order.

CASE WHEN dense_RANK() OVER (PARTITION by {custbody_case.number} ORDER BY {internalid})>1 THEN '**MULTIPLE SOs 1** 
Case:'||{custbody_case.number}||''  WHEN dense_RANK() OVER (PARTITION by {number} ORDER BY {internalid})>1 THEN '**MULTIPLE SOs 3** 
Case:'||{custbody_case.number}||'' WHEN dense_RANK() OVER (PARTITION by {custbody_case.number} ORDER BY {number})>1 THEN '**MULTIPLE SOs 4** 
Case:'||{custbody_case.number}||''  ELSE 'Case:'||{custbody_case.number}||'
' END

[Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Cet.png)

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as formatted text and not an image to make it easier for others to assist.

Answer (score 1):

RANK cannot take the place of COUNT. You can use analytic count by placing a comment between the function name and opening parentheses COUNT/*...*/(

You can also use NetSuite's grouping and utilize agragate COUNT inside a Minimum, Maximum, or Average

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by count.  I am wanting show ALL of the sales orders for a specific case because they each have there own tracking number.  But I want to show them together and notate that they are from the same case.. this way out dispatchers know that the case has multiple sales orders and multiple tracking numbers